# How to use a .scss file with Bootstrap SASS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I got a `style.scss` file for my website design. When including `css/bootstrap.css` (from bootstrap-3.3.7-dist) and the compiled `style.css` the site looks as expected.

But when putting the content of the `style.scss` file in Bootstrap's Drupal SASS starterkit's `_default-variables.scss` and including the compiled `style.css` (which is about ten times larger and obviously includes the bootstrap code) the site looks different in a few details (buttons, one spacing,...).

What is the right way to use the `style.scss` I got with Bootstrap SASS?

Thanks a lot!

Kind regards, 
Michael

Answer (score 0):

style.scss compiles to style.css, thus overwriting the previous style.css.

Any required changes to style.css should be done in style.scss, and recompiled to style.css.

Simply put, style.scss should be used only if you need to add updates to your style.css file. It would contain everything that is in style.css, just in a more readable format. There is no need to add link it on Drupal.

Please let me know if this is clear enough.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding concerning the style.css files. I put the SASS code in scss/_default-variables.scss and did sass scss/style.scss css/style.css. Then I included the css/style.css in my website and it looked diffrent.

Comment: Okay, I see. Sorry for the misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to put the content of the scss file in _default-variables.scss but to **import the file in `scss/styles.scss`**.